# Power contained in a signal

Tags: power-spectral-density, fourier-series

Given a signal $$x(t)=16\cos(20\pi t+\frac\pi 4)+6\cos(30\pi t+\frac\pi 6)+4\cos(40\pi t+\frac\pi 3)$$how can I calculate the **power contained in a frequency interval, say 12Hz to 22Hz**.
The total power is $\frac{16^2}{2}+\frac{6^2}{2}+\frac{4^2}{2}=154$

Comment: Determine the frequencies of the three sinusoids and then just count the ones inside the given interval.

Comment: thanks,I got it. It is the power of last two cos terms. 18+8=26W